# How to integrate our own player with Cobalt

Tags: cobalt

From the souce code of Cobalt, it can been seen that it used the ffmpeg related libraries(eg libasound/libavcodec/libavresample/libavutil...) to decode and render/play the video/audio as its own player(pull mode/push mode), as the playback code is high coupling from cobalt init to video decode, and there is no united interface for the use of integrating other player, so is there any guideline document or sample code to support/intergate other player except ffmpeg with Cobalt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The porting interface for the player is centered around `SbPlayer`, defined in `src/starboard/player.h` -- everything under `src/starboard/shared/` should be considered an example, or starter code for you to use to implement `SbPlayer`. You may use all or none of it as is convenient for you. The key is that you implement `SbPlayer`and the ancillary media porting APIs like `SbMedia` and `SbDrm`, and meet their described contracts.

Starboard (as defined in `src/starboard/*.h`) is the Cobalt porting interface, so you should not have to modify anything outside of your Starboard implementation in order to fully port Cobalt to a new platform. This will make later rebasing much easier as Starboard is a version-controlled API, but any other code is subject to change at any time, without warning. There are not and there won't ever be any direct references from Cobalt into any Starboard implementation code without going through the Starboard API, so you can swap out any portion of it as needed for your platform.